# Recording expectations in a method called from the instance initialiser

Tags: java, jmockit, expectations

I don't really understand the behaviour of the tests below. Looking at it, `test_OK` and `test_Not_OK` are strictly equivalent - the only difference is that `test_OK` has "inlined" `callMethod`.

However, `test_OK` passes whereas `test_Not_OK` fails. Is there a reason for that behaviour?

```
public class MethodCallTest {
    @Test
    public void test_Not_OK() {
        new NonStrictExpectations() {
            Whatever w;
            {
                callMethod();
            }
            private void callMethod() {
                w.method();
                result = 1;
            }
        };
        assertEquals(new Whatever().method(), 1); //fails
    }

    @Test
    public void test_OK() {
        new NonStrictExpectations() {
            Whatever w;
            {
                w.method();
                result = 1;
            }
        };
        assertEquals(new Whatever().method(), 1); //passes
    }

    public static class Whatever {
        public int method() {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. The reason is that JMockit performs certain transformations to the bytecode in constructors and initialization blocks of an `Expectations` or `NonStrictExpectations` subclass. (Essentially, this is done so that the mocking API works. For example, every assignment to the special `result` field is actually replaced with a method call, so that it gets properly associated with the current expectation.)

*Methods* in an expectation block, however, are not yet transformed. They should be, so I am implementing it now. From the next release (0.999.19) on, this will be supported.